# Does external css get applied to the pdfs generated by jsPDF

Tags: javascript, html, css, jspdf

I have started making some demos using jspdf. I have a html file and my css is in external file.

I have written the below code to generate my pdf

```
$('#pdfButton').on('click', function(){

   var pdf = new jsPDF('p','in','letter')
   , source = $('#main')[0]
   , specialElementHandlers = {
      '#bypassme': function(element, renderer){
      return true
      }
   }

  pdf.fromHTML(
     source // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
      , 0.5 // x coord
      , 0.5 // y coord
      , {
            'width':700 // max width of content on PDF
            , 'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
       }
   )
   pdf.output('dataurl');

   });


});
```

where **main** is the id of the div whose content I want to export as pdf.
The content is exporting as pdf but not the entire content(the pdf gets cut). It can be dynamic content. Also the css I have in external files are not getting applied , styles like **table-row**, background-color, etc are not getting applied.

How can I get my external css applied to the pdf before it is generated?
Is it even possible with jsPDF..? Any suggestions please.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know jsPDF doesnt take external css. It infact doesnt even take inline css. It is currently not suitable to use jspdf for converting html to pdf.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind that when you are PDF'ing things in HTML, it is essentially printing them to a file. This means you need to create a print stylesheet ideally, but also bear in mind that print stylesheets mean that it ignores things like background color. The way around this would be to have a background image in your print stylesheet that is the color.

Also see this article, http://css-tricks.com/dont-rely-on-background-colors-printing/

Hope that helps

Comment: can you give some links about print stylesheets pls

Comment: A print stylesheet is effectively the same as a normal stylesheet, however it has media="print" in the include.

Your main issue here is because you are trying to use background-color in your print stylesheet, which simply won't work, as it is a user setting for his printer or browser, not something that can be set by you. This is because not all users will have a colour printer.

Comment: currently  I am not worried about the colors, the only thing I am worried is I have a html table and i added some css to it, that table is not getting rendered as a table. but getting rendered as a scrambled text. Made changes to the question...thanks for your time

Comment: Setup a fiddle and I may be able to help

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/y2b7Q/327/ In this fiddle I have to get the pdf of the table as is, but we see a scrambled text,when we click on generate pdf

Comment: The fiddle doesn't actually work to save the pdf. Also you haven't included your css

Comment: fiddle is breaking sometimes, can you refresh once whenever fiddle breaks. I havent included the css, but for now to keep things basic, I need to get that table generated in the pdf as is..

Comment: the fiddle doesnt work at all in chrome..came to know just now. Can you please open it in firefox and let me know if it is working..?

Comment: So having a look at your fiddle, it now has become clear why it is all unstyled. You are actually sending through just a string representation of the DOM element. Which will obviously only print the innerHTML as a string, none of the styles are brought across. I'm not overly sure how the jsPDF library works, but it looks as if it tries to draw everything to canvas then save that out